# add links into haml template

Tags: html, css, haml

I implemented a template named "_list_two_lines"

```
%ul{:style=>"padding-top: 0; margin-top: 0"}
  - content.each do |element|
    %li{:style=>"font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; color: #333;font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px; "}
      &#10003;
      = render :partial => _text, :locals => {:inline =>true, :content => element[0] , :weight => bold_weight_email}
      %br
      = render :partial => _text, :locals => {:inline =>true, :content => element[1]}
```

Here I call it in the html.haml:

```
= render :partial => _list_two_lines, :locals => {:content => [["welcome to this forum","You need sign up first")]]}
```

How could I add a link to "sign up"? How could I achieve by modifying the template? So people will be redirect to another url clicking on sign up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `a` tag:

```
%a{href: '/sign_up'}
  Sign up
```

Obviously replacing the href value with whatever link you have. If you are using haml inside rails you may (or should) use the built in `link_to` methods:

```
=link_to sign_up_path
```

or something like that.

(Also - it is considered bad style to have inline CSS like that. Move it to a CSS file and include it in your page header and add a class or id to the element you want to style.)